# Visual Studio: Как изменить пробел на Tab в Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Как можно сделать так чтобы при нажатии Tab появилась табуляция а не 4 пробелы (в Visual Studio 2017)?

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > [язык] > Tabs > Keep tabs

Comment: 1. А на русском как?
2. Сделайте это ответом!

Comment: Потому что там я не вижу "Инструменты"

Comment: У меня англоязычная Студия. Не знаю, как это на русском. Возможно, Средства > Параметры. Короче, окно настроек. Если вы до сих пор не знаете про эти настройки, то...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На английской версии будет Tools → Options → Text Editor → [язык] → Tabs → Keep tabs (Ответ дал [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov)).

А на русской версии будет Средства → Параметры → Текстовый редактор → [Язык] → Табуляция → Сохранять знаки табуляции.